# Copy/Paste Item onto another sheet based on a single cell value

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, copy-paste

I am trying to create a macro that loops a copy/paste of items in (Column A) of my "Backend" worksheet based on a single cell's value (B2) onto my "Backend 2" Worksheet. To give some context, I have forecast data on building floors and trying to reformat my spreadsheet so that Tableau will read the dates as "dimensions." In order to accomplish this I would need a macro that would copy/paste my 83 floors of data 15 times for the 15 months in my forecast. I would also like the reference cell (B2) so that I can add months to the forecast if needed. Thanks!

Copy From:
[image]

Paste to:
[image]

---

The current answer allows me to copy one value type "floor," but I was wondering if I could run a macro that would copy/paste an entire row based on the copy amount. Please refer to the example below. I have 3 unique teams on sheet 1 that I want copied four times based on the cell L2 on sheet 2.

Before (Sheet 1)
[image]

After (Sheet 2)
[image]

Comment: Is the idea that the single value in `B` is the factor that you multiply each value in `A` by?

Comment: Yes. I have re-edit my question to show images of what I want copied to how I want the paste to look like. in this example I want the items to paste 3 times. I'm assuming that if I can do it for one "Floor" I would be able to use a loop? I am not sure what is the best way.

Comment: Will there only every be the one value in the copy column? Otherwise I'm not sure how you'd handle this

Comment: To answer your question simply, yes. Essentially, I have data on 83 building floors (which I would like to treat indiscriminately) and trying to make a forecast visual using Tableau. But in order for Tableau to identify the date as a "dimension" I would need a date field for every floor. So in this case, I am creating a 15 month forecast, which means I need every floor to repeat 15 times. B2 is a reference cell in case I have to add more months to the forecast. Thanks for reaching out!

Comment: Oh okay that makes this nice and easy then, I'll crank this out right now haha

Comment: Hello Marucciboy2, thanks for helping me last time. I was wondering if you could help me with a tweak in the code. Is there a way to consolidate the way I am using the code? Currently, I have one code for every column for each floor, but if I were to copy by row (as opposed to cell) that would save me from managing all the macros.

Comment: Could you upload a picture of what your source looks like when there are multiple floors or copies or whatever the case is ?

Comment: Hello Marcucciboy2, I re-edit the question with example image. Thanks again for helping!

Comment: Updated, let me know if it works

Comment: For the macro that copies the entire row, where would I indicate the two sheets? I pasted it after "Set ws2 = Sheets(2)" from the first macro and nothing happened.

Comment: Done. It will delete old copies though, so if you want to keep the new sheet it adds, rename it before running the script a second time

Comment: Thanks for working on this! I do not want the macro to delete the sheet because i have formulas in the sheet that is going to rely on the pasted in information. Is there any way to make the macro so that it does not delete the sheet? Also, where in the macro would i insert the name of the worksheets? The sheet that is being copied is called "Bcknd" and the sheet that is being pasted onto is called "Migration Plan Data Extract"

Comment: Updated. If you want other changes I'm inclined to tell you to research them or open a new question at this point, sorry

Comment: Thanks Marcucciboy2! It works and will do!

Comment: good to hear, glad it all worked out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
Sub floors()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = sheets("Bcknd")

    Dim ws2 As Worksheet

    If Not sheetExists("Migration Plan Data Extract") Then
        sheets.Add After:=ws1
        Set ws2 = sheets(ws1.index + 1)
        ws2.name = "Migration Plan Data Extract"
    Else
        Set ws2 = sheets("Migration Plan Data Extract")
    End If

    If Len(ws1.Range("B2").Value2) > 0 And IsNumeric(ws1.Range("B2").Value2) Then
        ws2.Range("A1").Value2 = ws1.Range("A1").Value2

        Dim vals As Variant
        vals = ws1.Range("A2:A" & ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value

        Dim i As Long
        Dim j As Long: j = 1

        For i = 1 To ws1.Range("B2").Value2 * UBound(vals)
            ws2.Range("A" & i + 1).Value2 = vals(j, 1)

            If i Mod ws1.Range("B2") = 0 Then
                j = j + 1
            End If
        Next i

    End If

End Sub
```

---

Alright, this should copy down the entire row :)

```
Sub floors2()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = sheets("Bcknd")

    If Len(ws1.Range("L2")) > 0 And IsNumeric(ws1.Range("L2").Value2) Then

        Dim ws2 As Worksheet

        If Not sheetExists("Migration Plan Data Extract") Then
            sheets.Add After:=ws1
            Set ws2 = sheets(ws1.index + 1)
            ws2.name = "Migration Plan Data Extract"
        Else
            Set ws2 = sheets("Migration Plan Data Extract")
        End If

        ws1.Range("A1:J1").copy Destination:=ws2.Range("A1:J1")

        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = ws1.Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row

        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = ws1.Range("A2:J" & lastRow)

        Dim currentRow As Long: currentRow = 2

        Dim i As Long
        Dim j As Long
        For i = 1 To rng.rows.count
            For j = 1 To ws1.Range("L2").Value2
                rng.rows(i).copy Destination:=ws2.Range("A" & currentRow)
                currentRow = currentRow + 1
            Next j
        Next i

    End If

End Sub
```

---

This sub is used by both to see if the sheet "Migration Plan Data Extract" already exists

```
Function sheetExists(sheetToFind As String) As Boolean

    sheetExists = False

    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    For Each sheet In Worksheets
        If sheetToFind = sheet.name Then
            sheetExists = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next sheet

End Function
```

Comment: To pick the right sheets for you, just replace the `1` in `sheets(1)` with the sheet's name surrounded by quotes, like this `sheets("sheet name")`

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test ,worded code resembles the following. **Modify the soucreSheet and targetWorksheet to yours**:

```
Sub Test11()

Dim rowCount As Long
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim targetWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim copyTimes As Integer

  Set sourceSheet = Worksheets("Sheet11")
  Set targetWorksheet = Worksheets("Sheet12")
    rowCount = targetWorksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

    copyTimes = CInt(sourceSheet.Cells(2, 2).Value)

    For i = 2 To sourceSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        MsgBox sourceSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value
        sourceSheet.Cells(i, 1).Copy
        For j = 1 To copyTimes
            targetWorksheet.Activate
            targetWorksheet.Cells(rowCount + 1, 1).Select
            targetWorksheet.Paste
            rowCount = rowCount + 1
        Next

            sourceSheet.Activate
    Next

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Seiyu for taking the time to create the code. I should have given more context. I have a list of 83 building floors that I needed copy pasted. So the msgbox was helpful, but a bit too much clicking for the process. Also, I would like the macro to stop when it gets to the last of the floor or the first blank cell. Thanks again!

Comment: After some research I found that "resizing" as opposed to "pasting" was better. So I landed on the following code. However, the code only pastes the first floor. So I placed a loop code, but it gives me the same result: Sub Test1()
      Dim x As Integer
      NumRows = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
      Range("A1").Select
      For x = 1 To NumRows
      
Dim y As Long
y = Sheets("Backend").Range("D1").Value
Worksheets("Backend 2").Range("A2").Resize(y).Value = Worksheets("Backend").Range("A1").Value

         ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
      Next
   End Sub

Comment: My computer don't have the dev env. I need to test your new context tomorrow. You should update the context to your quesiton but the commnets